# Jolt Transformation - Lowercase all keys?

Tags: json, transform, transformation, jolt

I've the following JSON:-

```
{
  "ROWNUM": "328938",
  "SOURCE_NAME": "I2323",
  "ID": "333333",
  "FIRST_NAME": "A121221",
  "KNOWN_AS": "G1223321",
  "LAST_NAME": "sadsadsd",
  "PLACE_OF_BIRTH": "Indsadsadsaddsaia",
  "DATE_OF_BIRTH": "sadsaddsa",
  "UPRN": "sadsadsad",
  "POST_CODE": "asdsadsda",
  "POST_TOWN": "GLASGOW",
  "ESTIMATED_DOB": "N",
  "LAST_UPDATED": "2019-02-11T13:57:05.264Z",
  "cluster_id": 3020,
  "aliases": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "timestamp": 1550152767,
        "machineIdentifier": 6505561,
        "processIdentifier": 59,
        "counter": 2775622,
        "time": 1550152767000,
        "timeSecond": 1550152767,
        "date": 1550152767000
      },
      "ROWNUM": "328938",
      "SOURCE_NAME": "I2323",
      "ID": "333333",
      "FIRST_NAME": "A121221",
      "KNOWN_AS": "G1223321",
      "LAST_NAME": "sadsadsd",
      "PLACE_OF_BIRTH": "Indsadsadsaddsaia",
      "DATE_OF_BIRTH": "sadsaddsa",
      "UPRN": "sadsadsad",
      "POST_CODE": "asdsadsda",
      "POST_TOWN": "GLASGOW",
      "ESTIMATED_DOB": "N",
      "LAST_UPDATED": "2019-02-11T13:57:05.264Z",
      "cluster_id": 3020,
      "score": "0.9997580647468567"
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "timestamp": 1550152767,
        "machineIdentifier": 6505561,
        "processIdentifier": 59,
        "counter": 2775622,
        "time": 1550152767000,
        "timeSecond": 1550152767,
        "date": 1550152767000
      },
      "ROWNUM": "328938",
      "SOURCE_NAME": "I2323",
      "ID": "333333",
      "FIRST_NAME": "A121221",
      "KNOWN_AS": "G1223321",
      "LAST_NAME": "sadsadsd",
      "PLACE_OF_BIRTH": "Whatever",
      "DATE_OF_BIRTH": "sadsaddsa",
      "UPRN": "sadsadsad",
      "POST_CODE": "asdsadsda",
      "POST_TOWN": "PAISLEY",
      "ESTIMATED_DOB": "N",
      "LAST_UPDATED": "2019-02-11T13:57:05.264Z",
      "cluster_id": 3020,
      "score": "0.9997580647468567"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a jolt spec that would lowercase every key, including keys in nested objects? (in this case what is under `aliases`).

The following works for the top level keys but not for the nested ones:

```
[
  {
    // unwrap the keys and values into literal
    // "key" : "A", "value" : "b"
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "&1.key",
        "@": "&1.value"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        // Now that the origional key
        //  is on the "right hand side"
        //  lowercase it
        "key": "=toLower"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // pivot back, the now lowercased keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "value": "@(1,key)"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: what about regex?
If you type in a regex like this: ".*": then every key is matched

Comment: I was hoping to keep things less brittle using a jolt transform, but if all hope is lost I might consider that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This produces the desired result extending the existing transformation:

```
[
  {
    // unwrap the keys and values into literal
    // "key" : "A", "value" : "b"
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "&1.key",
        "@": "&1.value"
      },
      //do the same for everything in aliases
      //&3 = aliases
      //&2 = array position
      //&1 = position of kvp
      "aliases": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "$": "&3.&2.&1.key",
            "@": "&3.&2.&1.value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        // Now that the origional key
        //  is on the "right hand side"
        //  lowercase it
        "key": "=toLower"
      },
      "aliases": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            // Now that the origional key
            //  is on the "right hand side"
            //  lowercase it
            "key": "=toLower"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // pivot back, the now lowercased keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "value": "@(1,key)"
      },
      "aliases": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            //&3 = aliases
            //&2 = array postion
            //@(1,key) values from "key"
            "value": "&3.[&2].@(1,key)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Produces the following:

```
{
  "rownum": "328938",
  "source_name": "I2323",
  "id": "333333",
  "first_name": "A121221",
  "known_as": "G1223321",
  "last_name": "sadsadsd",
  "place_of_birth": "Indsadsadsaddsaia",
  "date_of_birth": "sadsaddsa",
  "uprn": "sadsadsad",
  "post_code": "asdsadsda",
  "post_town": "GLASGOW",
  "estimated_dob": "N",
  "last_updated": "2019-02-11T13:57:05.264Z",
  "cluster_id": 3020,
  "aliases": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "timestamp": 1550152767,
        "machineIdentifier": 6505561,
        "processIdentifier": 59,
        "counter": 2775622,
        "time": 1550152767000,
        "timeSecond": 1550152767,
        "date": 1550152767000
      },
      "rownum": "328938",
      "source_name": "I2323",
      "id": "333333",
      "first_name": "A121221",
      "known_as": "G1223321",
      "last_name": "sadsadsd",
      "place_of_birth": "Indsadsadsaddsaia",
      "date_of_birth": "sadsaddsa",
      "uprn": "sadsadsad",
      "post_code": "asdsadsda",
      "post_town": "GLASGOW",
      "estimated_dob": "N",
      "last_updated": "2019-02-11T13:57:05.264Z",
      "cluster_id": 3020,
      "score": "0.9997580647468567"
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "timestamp": 1550152767,
        "machineIdentifier": 6505561,
        "processIdentifier": 59,
        "counter": 2775622,
        "time": 1550152767000,
        "timeSecond": 1550152767,
        "date": 1550152767000
      },
      "rownum": "328938",
      "source_name": "I2323",
      "id": "333333",
      "first_name": "A121221",
      "known_as": "G1223321",
      "last_name": "sadsadsd",
      "place_of_birth": "Whatever",
      "date_of_birth": "sadsaddsa",
      "uprn": "sadsadsad",
      "post_code": "asdsadsda",
      "post_town": "PAISLEY",
      "estimated_dob": "N",
      "last_updated": "2019-02-11T13:57:05.264Z",
      "cluster_id": 3020,
      "score": "0.9997580647468567"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a custom [`JsonParserDelegate`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/JsonParserDelegate.html) parser as demonstrated in the following test.

A working project can be check out from https://github.com/hovanessyan/json_lowercase_all_keys.git

a) create your own parser that lowercase the keys (`KeysToLowercaseParser`)

b) Override the JsonFactory and use the new Parser

I've pasted your json content in `test.json`, which is read in this test.

```
public class LowerCaseJsonTest {

    @Test
    public void name() throws IOException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new JsonFactory() {
            @Override
            protected JsonParser _createParser(byte[] data, int offset, int len, IOContext ctxt) throws IOException {
                return new KeysToLowercaseParser(super._createParser(data, offset, len, ctxt));
            }

            @Override
            protected JsonParser _createParser(InputStream in, IOContext ctxt) throws IOException {
                return new KeysToLowercaseParser(super._createParser(in, ctxt));
            }

            @Override
            protected JsonParser _createParser(Reader r, IOContext ctxt) throws IOException {
                return new KeysToLowercaseParser(super._createParser(r, ctxt));
            }

            @Override
            protected JsonParser _createParser(char[] data, int offset, int len, IOContext ctxt, boolean recyclable)
                    throws IOException {
                return new KeysToLowercaseParser(super._createParser(data, offset, len, ctxt, recyclable));
            }
        });


        File file = new File("src/main/resources/test.json");
        JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(file);
        String output = mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonNode);
        System.out.println(output);
    }

}

class KeysToLowercaseParser extends JsonParserDelegate {
    KeysToLowercaseParser(JsonParser d) {
        super(d);
    }

    @Override
    public String getCurrentName() throws IOException {
        if (hasTokenId(JsonTokenId.ID_FIELD_NAME)) {
            return delegate.getCurrentName().toLowerCase();
        }
        return delegate.getCurrentName();
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() throws IOException {
        if (hasTokenId(JsonTokenId.ID_FIELD_NAME)) {
            return delegate.getText().toLowerCase();
        }
        return delegate.getText();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I was really looking for a Jolt spec since I'm wanting to integrate this into an Apache Nifi pipeline (with a Jolt processor), but I'll give you the rep just for the effort you put into that answer. Thanks! (Edit: says I can only award the bounty in 15 hours but will do.)

Comment: Hey, thanks but I didn't realize you were looking for a Jolt specific answer. Why don't you wait the whole bounty period - maybe someone will answer with a Jolt based solution.

Comment: Ok I will do, I should have been more clear in my question. If it all else fails I'll look at wrapping your code with an ExecuteScript processor in Nifi perhaps. Thanks again!